# inserting into Global array from AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk

my script contains code like below, I am reading a file and for every row I will be fetching 4 column values on that row and forming a key like this `key = col1-col3-col5-col7`, I want  to insert this into my hashmap as key and value as 1.

```
i.e declare -A arr
((arr[$key]++))
```

Below is my code:
declare -A hash

GetReport() {

```
`cat sample.txt | grep -v Orig |awk '
BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS="," }
{
hk=$1"-"$3"-"$5"-"$7
((hash[$hk]++))
}'`
```

I am not able to insert this key into my hashArray, Any idea how to write into array inside the awk, so that I can have the global access to the array and I can process the data from different methods also

Comment: `awk` and `bash` are different languages. It is *usually* not a good idea to mix them up. What you're trying to do in `bash` can be done easily in `awk` itself. As a side note `cat` and `grep` are redundant in your code. If you clarify your requirements further we can suggest a solution.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, I am reading a file in which each fields are seperated by | , and every field is  in this form key1:value1|key2:value2. The code which I shared is partial, I am fetching the required fields then forming the key like this value1-value3-value5 something like this. ex: 2021-02-24-200  --> this is my key, there might be a chance where identical row comes in , So I thought of maintaining this in HashMap,the above key going to be the key of my hashMap, and value going to be the (counter),if same row comes again so for that key the value going to be 2. So I can perfrom other operations

Comment: If I write it to file its going to be I/O from disk I will be doing to avoid that I want to maintain that in the HashMap like structure

Comment: All that can be done easily in `awk`'s associative arrays (identical to `HashMap`)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to print the array generation within awk and redirect back into source to create the actual array.

Run the awk command on it's own first to verify that the array entries are being created as expected before redirecting back into source.

```
source <(awk '
     BEGIN{ 
            FS="|"; OFS="," 
            print "declare -A hash"
          }
     !/Orig/{
            hk=$1"-"$3"-"$5"-"$7;
            print "(( hash[\""hk"\"]++ ))"
            }' sample.txt)
```

Comment: Hi Raman, I dont want to write into the file,  after reading each row from input file storing that in the Map ,how to add and increment its count in map inside the awk?

Comment: You're not, you are creating an associative array called hash. This will be generated by awk but then available at bash level.